# How can I get Windows 10 to zoom old icons above 200%?

Tags: windows-10, icons, zoom

This is the icon for PuTTY at 175%, 200%, 225%, & 250% zoom:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

In comparison, here is the icon for Word at 175%, 200%, 225%, & 250% zoom:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

All my programs that use old style icons have the same problem as PuTTY. Programs using the newer icon format display properly like Word does.

How can I get the old style icons to display correctly when the screen is zoomed above 200%?

Comment: Program have their icons compiled into them at set sizes. EG Notepad has 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48, 256x256 and except for the largest size are in 16 colours and 256 colours and all sizes at 16.8 million colours. While Notepad from Windows Vista has 16x16, 32x32 , and 48x48 only. You cannot scale small pictures beyond a small amount.

Comment: @Mark You can scale small images as much as you want. They may look terrible, but they can still be scaled.

Comment: Well Microsoft disagrees with you. That's why they don't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have to use one of the old icon managers to build a larger icon. Old programs and their icons were not built to zoom and still look good.

Try something like this to build your own icons

https://icoconvert.com/

Comment: They still zoom up to 200% even though they were not built to zoom.

Comment: I added an icon maker for you to consider. There is a limit to what Windows 10 can do with old programs.